# WooCommerce Wootique theme product images not aligning vertically

Tags: image, alignment, woocommerce, product

I am using WooCommerce with Wootique Theme.  On the product page, which is the index page, I am trying to have only 2 images on the same line. When I add the 3rd image it does not go to a new line but sits on the same line with the other 2 images. If I try to enlarge the images they cover each other.  I do not know how to specific in the code that I only want 2 images on a line.

I tried different adjustment in my custom CSS style sheet but nothing is working.

The code below was given for a similar question, but I do not know if it will solve my problem since I would like to have 2 images and not 1 on the same line.  I would like to have the 3rd and 4th images on a new line, the 5th and 6th on a new line etc.

```
  {assign var=lines value="\n"|explode:$product.description|strip_tags}
       <ul>
            {foreach key=k item=line from=$lines}
            <li>{$line}</li>
            {/foreach}
       </ul>
```

If this is the correct code, where would I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to functions.php file

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 2; // 2 products per row
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Anand,  I pasted your code in  the  functions.php file but it does not work.  When I add the 3rd image it forced itself on the same line with the other 2 images.

Comment: This is what the code looks like in inspect element:<img width="300" height="300" src="http:/xxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/IMG_20150406_115638_564-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Tapestry bags">

Comment: Someone please help!  I only want 2 images on a line.

Comment: Please check in Wootique theme settings if there's an option to display 2 in a row.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get 2 images on a line in the WooCommerce Theme by going into the index.php page and change the column number to 2.  It was showing 3 for the column and that is why when I added the 3rd image it was lining up horizontally with the other 2 images. When I changed the column to 2 the 3rd image started on a new line.

Below is the code that I changed in the index.php page.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[recent_products per_page="12" columns="2"]' ); ?>
```

Anand, I believe your code would also work but I did realize that I had to change the function name to do_shortcode.  Thanks for the help it forced me to start looking at the different pages in the theme.